# How do I evaluate the Clifford product in dimensions greater than 3?

Tags: exterior-algebra, clifford-algebras

The Clifford product of a pair of vectors $a,b$ is an associative operation defined by

$$ ab = a \cdot b + a \wedge b.$$

In sufficiently low dimensions I am used to being able to define the Clifford product on arbitrary $k$-vectors by repeatedly applying the vector definition.  For instance, suppose that I build a Clifford algebra over $\mathbb{R}^3$ with the usual (positive) Euclidean inner product.  Then I can easily write out the Clifford product of *any* pair of basis bivectors.  For instance,

$$ e_{12}e_{13} = e_1 e_2 e_1 e_3 = -e_2(e_1 e_1)e_3 = -e_2 (1) e_3 = -e_{23}.$$

In four dimensions I get stuck, because it's possible that two of the indices don't "cancel," and then I don't know how to apply the product:

$$e_{12}e_{34} = e_1 e_2 e_3 e_4.$$

Where do I go from here?  I strongly suspect that this equals just $e_{1234}$, but I don't know how to show (in an explicit, pedantic, algebraic way) that

$$e_1 e_2 e_3 e_4 = e_1 \wedge e_2 \wedge e_3 \wedge e_4.$$

Thanks!

Comment: $e_i \cdot e_j = 0$

Comment: ...and for orthogonal vectors, the Clifford product coincides with the wedge product.

Comment: What you seem to be calling an 
"explicit, pedantic, algebraic way" is what most people would call "a proof"...

Comment: Ok, well I want a proof that for orthogonal vectors the Clifford product coincides with the wedge product.  In other words, I certainly realize that $e_i e_j = e_i \cdot e_j + e_i \wedge e_j = 0 + e_{ij}$ when $i \ne j$.  But now suppose I have $e_i e_j e_k$ for distinct $i$, $j$, and $k$.  Then I get $e_{ij} e_k$ but have no rule for the Clifford product between a bivector and a vector, so I am stuck!  Thanks for the help.

Comment: I agree with Hans; there's nothing to say until you tell us what your definition of the Clifford algebra is.

Answer (score 5):

It's not easy to give a proof without knowing exactly what your
definitions of the Clifford and exterior algebras are, so the
following argument is still a little handwaving. But let's say that we
somehow have defined what the exterior algebra of a vector space $V$
is; we know that its elements are multivectors, and the rule which
generates everything is that $x \wedge y + y \wedge x=0$ if $x$ and
$y$ are vectors in $V$. The Clifford algebra has the same
elements as the exterior algebra, and the same linear space structure,
but the multiplication is different: it is generated by the rule
$xy+yx=2 \, Q(x,y)$ where $Q$ is the inner product on $V$. Since
"orthogonal" means that $Q(e_i,e_j)=0$, it shouldn't be too hard to
believe that the Clifford and exterior multiplications agree for
orthogonal vectors.

Maybe [this section on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clifford_algebra#Relation_to_the_exterior_algebra) can be of some help too?

Answer (score 3):

It appears that you are thinking in terms of "geometric algebra".
For those unfamliar with this doctrine, it's a way of regarding
the Clifford algebra on an inner product space $(V,Q)$ and the exterior algebra
on the $V$ as the same set, but with different product operations.
Let's stick to a ground field of characteristic zero. Then the Clifford
algebra $C$ of $(V,Q)$ is generated by the elements $v\in V$ with relations
$vv=Q(v)$. Now for $v_1,\ldots,v_k\in V$ one can define wedge product
$$v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k
=\frac1{k!}\sum_{\pi\in S_k}(-1)^{\text{sgn}(\pi)}v_{\pi(1)}v_{\pi(2)}\cdots
v_{\pi(k)}\in C.$$
This wedge product identifies $C$ with the exterior algebra $\bigwedge(V)$.

With this definition, Hans's comments are absolutely right. If
$v_1,\ldots,v_k$ are pairwise orthogonal then the Clifford product
$v_1v_2\cdots v_k$ equals the exterior product
$v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k$, and this is certainly the case
for orthogonal basis vectors: $e_1 e_2 e_3 e_4
=e_1\wedge e_2\wedge e_3\wedge e_4$.